# How To Model A String List in EMF ECORE

Tags: eclipse, emf, ecore

I'm stuck trying to use ecore annotations to model a List for the type attribute I have tried the type="java.lang.String" and type="EString" but both are not getting the results I want. When using annotations to model a simple String getter/setter it works fine but now I'm stuck using an object holder for a string for string lists and its getting annoying. Does anyone have an idea? - Duncan

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why are you using annotations to model a List.

To model an attribute as a List of Strings, just define the EType as EString and Upper Bound to -1.